# Hortonworks HDP 2.2.6 namenode will not start

Tags: hadoop, centos, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

my namenode will not start both during the installation phase of the cluster and after the installation process. the install finished with warnings because the namenode would not start. here is the error message from Ambari.

> resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ; /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf start namenode'' returned 1. starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hostname.out

Here are the contents of my /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-.out file:

- ulimit -a for user hdfs
- core file size      (blocks, -c) unlimited
- data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
- scheduling priority (-e) 0
- file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
- pending signals (-i) 1031397
- max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64
- max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited
- open files (-n) 32768
- pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
- POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
- real-time priority (-r) 0
- stack size (kbytes, -s) 10240
- cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
- max user processes (-u) 65536
- virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited
- file locks (-x) unlimited

Comment: That's all the log contained? Is there also a  /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hostname.log file?